# During `git add -p`, I get error: hunks do not overlap

Tags: git

I executed a `git add -p` and got to a file with a fairly large diff hunk, so I hit "s" to split it and I got this in my editor:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide.
@@ -1,6 +1,9 @@
-﻿namespace Monitor.Deployment;
+using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
+using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels;
+
+namespace Monitor.Deployment;
 
 public static class CompositionRoot
 {
     public static void Setup(IServiceCollection services)
     {
# ---
```

I want to remove the two `using` statements as well as the space after it. So I simply removed those 3 lines to get this:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide.
@@ -1,6 +1,9 @@
-﻿namespace Monitor.Deployment;
+namespace Monitor.Deployment;

 public static class CompositionRoot
 {
     public static void Setup(IServiceCollection services)
     {
# ---
```

One thing worth noting that you can't see here, is that on the first line where it says `-namespace`, there's actually a UTF-8 BOM, which was removed in the `+namespace` line below it. So it actually looks like this in my editor:

[image]

I don't know if this matters for the purposes of this error, though.

After I save & close the editor, it fails to apply the hunk with this error:

```
error: hunks do not overlap:
-﻿namespace Monitor.Deployment;?
+namespace Monitor.Deployment;?
?
 public static class CompositionRoot?
 {?
     public static void Setup(IServiceCollection services)?
     {?

        does not end with:
     {

error: corrupt patch at line 8
error: 'git apply --cached' failed
```

I have no idea how to interpret this error. I have no idea what the issue is. I've edited hunks like this before, and never had this issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 's'plit shouldn't put you into editor mode, 'e'dit does

Comment: Not sure what those question-marks represent, but the BOM does matter - Git needs the updated diff to match exactly, including any BOMs.

Comment: Note that `git add -p` has been undergoing a rewrite in C, so the exact Git version here may matter: old versions of Git will use perl to read and whack on the diffs, new ones will use C code, and it's easy for UTF-8, i18n, CRLF, etc., issues to sneak in here.

Comment: How is the editor supposed to render BOM characters in edit mode? I think the issue is that the BOM is not part of the diff so the removed line doesn't match exactly. As for version: I'm using the latest version at the time of posting; I don't have my dev environment handy right now to get you an exact number.